# Determine type of terrain at location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, terrain

I'm trying to determine the terrain type at an arbitrary location. If I make use of Google Maps for instance, I can visually see what terrain is forest, built up areas and water for instance by the colour displayed on the map.

I'm trying to see whether there's any sort of API call I can use to get this basic information. I don't need it to be highly precise and I don't really need to determine the exact terrain type (so stuff like the Corine Land Cover is pure overkill). I'm going to need to make a number of these requests every few minutes. I've [found a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362255/get-type-of-terrain-by-coordinate) around 3 years ago which wasn't really resolved, I'm hoping that there's been a change now.

Is there anything I can use? I'm actually considering reading the displayed map tile myself and grabbing the pixel colour, but I'd appreciate if there was a simpler method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem like they provided the API to do that..

A work around would be to use their static maps API.

basically after you turn off everything but the water and greens, you get something like this:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7833,-122.4167&zoom=10&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=visibility:off&style=feature:water|element:geometry|visibility:simplified&style=feature:poi.park|element:geometry|visibility:on](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.7833,-122.4167&zoom=10&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=visibility:off&style=feature:water%7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:simplified&style=feature:poi.park%7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:on)

you can, make the size to be 1px by 1px, zoom in, and check the color of this image to decide the type of area of this location.